# PopUp Confirmations in Salesforce Setup not working in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, salesforce-classic, setup, chrome

Recently I've had an issue come when I am doing any changes in Setup that require you to confirm via the usual pop up confirmation.  This is only in Lightning.  I then have to switch to Classic just to get the confirmation to appear.

Today's example: I am trying to remove an override for the New button on a custom object.  In Lightning, nothing happens when you try to save it.

But in Classic I get this and I can click OK and make my change:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome! what browser are you using (and what version) and have you tried a different one to see if the same behavior occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [recent changes](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5148698084376576#details) to cross-origin iframe Javascript dialogs in Chrome 92. There's the following [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=salesforce-functionality-impacted-in-%5B%E2%80%A6%5Doss-origin-iframe-javascript-dialogs&Id=a1p4V000002BRMX) that calls this out.

The current workarounds are the following:

1. Use alternative browser (Firefox or Safari)
2. Add the following flag `--disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"` to your Goolge Chrome Shortcut ([see here for more info](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwindows))

Edit: This has been fixed.